# Append/Prepend a different character to each item in a list

Tags: python, list, append, prepend

Starting with a list such as:

```
['aaaa', 'aaata', 'aaatt']
```

How could I prepend a different character to that start of each item denoting its order, i.e. produce a list that went:

```
['>1/naaaa', '>2/naaata', '>3/naaatt']
```

Thank you

Comment: The last item in your first list should be `'aaatt'` as opposed to `aaatt'`; minor typo.

Comment: Oops sorry! Thanks for correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> lst = ['aaaa', 'aaata', 'aaatt']
>>> [">{}/n{}".format(x, y) for x,y in enumerate(lst, 1)]
['>1/naaaa', '>2/naaata', '>3/naaatt']
>>>
```

---

**Edit:**

Regarding your comment, all you need is [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#ascii_lowercase):

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> ascii_lowercase  # Just to demonstrate
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> lst = ['aaaa', 'aaata', 'aaatt']
>>> [">{}/n{}".format(ascii_lowercase[x], y) for x,y in enumerate(lst)]
['>a/naaaa', '>b/naaata', '>c/naaatt']
>>>
```

Comment: would there be any way of making it go a,b,c,d.... rather than 1,2,3,4,5 etc? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this:

```
alist = ['aaaa', 'aaata', 'aaatt']
output = ['>{}/n{}'.format(idx, ele) for idx, ele in enumerate(alist, start=1)]
```

prints

```
['>1/naaaa', '>2/naaata', '>3/naaatt']
```